# Powershell to click a drop down bar and select an option with in it

Tags: powershell

I've been looking at a few of the answer and seem to not be able to get my code to click the drop-down and select an option.

I've just started to learn PowerShell to automate updating data from a spreadsheet to a site.

```
<select name="ev_43980_Location.Racked" width="100" class="select">
<option value="0">!! Unknown !!</option>
<option value="2">No</option>
<option value="1" selected="">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Currently, my bit of code, What it should do is select the answer no. This may be completely wrong. But getting no error or response back through powershell to say.

```
$racked = $ie.document.getElementsByname("ev_57152_Location.Racked") 
($racked | where {$_.innerHTML -eq "2"}).Selected = $true
```

I add $racked at the end to test what it get's feedback and nothing comes back through the test,

Any help will be appreciated or way's to test it.

I've figured out why it isn't finding it is with inside another field box, So the command isn't searching there it searches the first section it lands it on that page and as that is it's own field box it isn't jumping out of that and searching the next one. Any ideas on how to get it to tab across?

It drops in to this one first which has a load of field in side it

```
<table id="toggle_id1" width="450" class="expanderShow1" style="display: block;">
<!-- end of expander table head -->
```

I want it to go and look in the other block which is this one.

```
<table id="toggle_id7" width="450" class="expanderShow1">
<!-- end of expander table head -->
```

As that is where the object is located.

Comment: Check to see if `$racked` has a `SetActive()` method you can call.  You can look at the methods for it by running `$racked | get-member -memberType Method`.  If it does, run `$racked.SetActive()`, or `$racked.Click()`.

Comment: No joy on this, Looking at the site code. it drops it into one enity table but then for some strange reason PowerShell will not go into the other tables even though they are on the same page.